# Related previous posts inside of detail view

Tags: django

In my PostDetailView I'm trying to display previous posts for the Game that is related to the Post in the PostDetailView. I'm unsure of how to filter Post by the game in the PostDetailView

```
 class Game(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover_images')  



    class Post(models.Model):
            author = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,
                                       null=True, )  # If user is deleted keep all updates by said user
            article_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="Use format: Release Notes for MM/DD/YYYY")
            content = models.TextField()
            date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now,
                                                  help_text="Use date of update not current time")
            game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Edit:

I'm only displaying one post in the PostDetailView. However on the side I want to a list of all previous posts (this will link to a new postdetailview for that post) in the same game(ForeignKeyed into Game model) as the Post in the PostDetailView

Comment: What do you mean by previous post list?

Comment: Are you trying to show more than one 1 post?

Comment: Are you trying to show multiple objects or a single one? DetailView is generally used for showing a single object of a model, if you want to show multiple objects you should use ListView instead.

Comment: Edited my post to try and better explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include other elements in the template context via `get_context_data`. You may want to change how to fetch the related products, but this shows the general idea.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.select_related('game')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'related': self.get_object().game.post_set.all()
        })
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
game = Post.objects.filter(game__title__contains = "Name of the game")
```

Anyway, like the others said in the comments, you can't use a DetailView for this (because that only gets one object indexed by the url), but may want to use a ListView or a simple function based view

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a DetailView, write your own view from scratch and load both Games and Posts into it.

Also, your indentation of the Post class should be on the same level as your Game class.